# how to display sql query out in bit-by-bit in form of list (<li>). php codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have an sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_std FROM `login`  WHERE `login_account_type` =
'STUDENT'  AND `login_account_status` = 'ACTIVE'
```

The out of this query is 3910. I want to display the result bit by bit, not as a whole number. For example I want an output like this:

> - 3
> - 9
> - 1
> - 0

Note that I am using PHP Codeigniter. 
Please Help.

Comment: <ul> <?php foreach(...) { ?><li> <?php echo $number ?></li> <?php } ?> </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)** to split 3910 as

```
$str = "3910";

$arr2 = str_split($str, 1);

echo "<ul>"; 
foreach($arr2 as $number) { 
echo "<li>".  $number."</li>" ;

}
echo "</ul> ";
```

Comment: Will good practice be casting data type like `(string)$db_result`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input1=1234;
$str="<ul>";
foreach(str_split($input1) as $item)
{
$str.="<li>".$item."</li>";
}

$str.="</ul>";
echo $str;

?>
```

explanation:
using str_split you can split your string to character by character then append your styles to characters.